# Deploy App on Azure in the same app service?

Tags: azure, docker, nginx

I wanna move my app (React for frontend and Nodejs for backend) on azure, publishing everything in the same app services. I tried to use docker and docker compose but i was not able to let the app works. There is a way to upload the app in this way or is a wrong apporach?

Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, [Create a multi-container (preview) app using a Docker Compose configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-multi-container) provides an overview of running a multi-container application on app service.

If you weren't able to get it working, check the [container logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-linuxcontainer). A simple gotcha is the platform wasn't able to bind to your front-end image so double check your exposed port configuration.